# Is there a known issue resuming downloads from IIS with curl?

Tags: iis, curl

I am seeing an issue when trying to resume a download using curl as follows:

```
curl -L -s -C - -o 'file.data' 'https://sever/file'
```

The issue is only with IIS. I tried several other web servers on OSX and linux and never had any issues resuming a download.

Specifically, I turn off Wi-Fi half way through the download of a large file, and then turn the Wi-Fi back on.

Yes, we have some scenarios where we have to use IIS.

Comment: Connect to the FTP server and issue the literal FEAT command, and post the response.

Comment: Here is what I get:211-Extended features supported:
 LANG EN*
 UTF8
 AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
 PBSZ
 PROT C;P;
 CCC
 HOST
 SIZE
 MDTM
 REST STREAM
211 END